# Add leading zeros twice in filename

Tags: linux, bash, rename, leading-zero

I have file names (from image tiles) consisting of two numbers separated by an underscore, e.g.

```
142_27.jpg
7_39.jpg
1_120.jpg
```

How can I (in linux) add leading zeros to both of these numbers? What I want is the file names as

```
142_027.jpg
007_039.jpg
001_120.jpg
```

Comment: you are looking to rename files or change text in a file?

Comment: Rename files. I found many examples for adding zeros to the start of a file name, but here I want zeros in two places (at the beginning and after the underscore.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl` based `rename` command

```
$ touch 142_27.jpg 7_39.jpg 1_120.jpg
$ rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%03d", $&/ge' *.jpg
rename(1_120.jpg, 001_120.jpg)
rename(142_27.jpg, 142_027.jpg)
rename(7_39.jpg, 007_039.jpg)
```

The `-n` option is for dry run, remove it for actual renaming

If `perl` based `rename` command is not available:

```
$ for f in *.jpg; do echo mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf "%03d", $&/ge')"; done
mv 1_120.jpg 001_120.jpg
mv 142_27.jpg 142_027.jpg
mv 7_39.jpg 007_039.jpg
```

Change `echo mv` to just `mv` once dry run seems okay

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `awk` command to format filenames with leading zeroes using a `printf`:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
   echo mv "$f" $(awk -F '[_.]' '{printf "%03d_%03d.%s", $1, $2, $3}' <<< "$f")
done
```

This will output:

```
mv 142_27.jpg 142_027.jpg
mv 1_120.jpg 001_120.jpg
mv 7_39.jpg 007_039.jpg
```

Once you're satisfied with the output, remove `echo` before `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a little shell-script using sed:

```
for i in *.jpg;
do
    new=`echo "$i" | sed -n -e '{ s/^\([0-9]\{0,3\}\)_\([0-9]\{0,3\}\).jpg/000\1_000\2.jpg/ };
    {s/\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)_\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{3\}\).jpg/\2_\4.jpg/p };'`;
    mv "$i" "$new";
done;
```

I first append three leading zeros at the said places by default and afterwards cut off as many digits as necessary brginning at the start at said places so that only 3 digits are left

Answer (score 0):

with bash substitution(a,b)

windows(bash)

```
for f in *.jpg;do a=${f%_*};b=${f#*_};mv $f $(printf "%03d_%07s" $a $b);done
```

linux

```
for f in *.jpg;do a=${f%_*};b=${f#*_};b=${b%.*};mv $f $(printf "%03d_%03d".jpg $a $b);done
```